# How to sniff / monitor SVN protocol messages? (or any TCP messages from an application)

Tags: svn, sniffer

I would like to monitor all incomming SVN protocol requests / repsonses from an SVN server (1.6, using collabnet edge 1.3.1). Or another option, to monitor all SVN trafic comming from the client (.NET app)

I don't mind writing some code for it, but I'm sure there should be a straight forward way for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using apache with webdav as a frontend for subversion; you can view the apache access logs.